# Escaping closures give linker errors in Release configuration

Tags: ios, swift, linker, closures

I am developing an iOS app.

For my server API requests I use Alamofire wrapper methods which, among other parameters, take `@escaping` closures – usually for success, failure and handling loading indicators. The closures themselves are declared as `lazy var`s in my ViewControllers subclasses. An example of such closure:

```
lazy var sendRequestSuccess = {() -> Void in
    // do something here
}
```

How I call my API wrapper methods:

```
APIRequestHelper.sharedInstance.sendRequest(success: requestSuccess, progress: animateActivityIndicator, failure: requestFailure)
// APIRequestHelper is my class for all API requests
```

And my API methods in general case look like this:

```
func sendRequest(success: @escaping () -> Void, progress: @escaping (AnimationAction) -> Void, failure: @escaping (String?) -> Void)  {
// Alamofire request sending and response handling goes here
}
```

**My issue**

When I build my app in `Debug` configuration, everything builds and runs smoothly. However, in `Release` configuration all of my `@escaping` closures (96 of them so far) generate linker errors looking like this:

```
"__TFFC8<my app name>27AddressPickerViewControllerg23getPlaceLocationFailureFGSqSS_T_auL_4selfS0_", referenced from:
      __TTSf4d___TFFC8<my app name>27AddressPickerViewControllerg23getPlaceLocationFailureFGSqSS_T_U_FGSqSS_T_ in AddressPickerViewController.o
  "__TFFC8<my app name>26RequestsListViewControllerg22getRequestsListSuccessFGSqGSaCS_5Order__T_auL_4selfS0_", referenced from:
      __TTSf4g___TFFC8<my app name>26RequestsListViewControllerg22getRequestsListSuccessFGSqGSaCS_5Order__T_U_FGSqGSaS1___T_ in RequestsListViewController.o
  "__TFFC8<my app name>19LoginViewControllerg19getCountriesFailureFGSqSS_T_auL_4selfS0_", referenced from:
      __TTSf4g___TFFC8<my app name>19LoginViewControllerg19getCountriesFailureFGSqSS_T_U_FGSqSS_T_ in LoginViewController.o
```

with a couple more additional messages:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**What I tried**

As per a few other SO questions that refer to linker errors, I made sure I have `$(inherited)` in my "Other Linker Flags" in Build Settings > Linking. In fact, the options (libraries listed) there are the same for both `Debug` and `Release` configurations. I have also tried switching "Build Active Architecture Only" in Build Settings > Architectures on and off. 
However, most such questions are related to various third-party libraries while in my case `@escaping` closures, which are a part of the language itself, seem to cause trouble.

This is the first issue in my developer career that caused me to write my own SO question so big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had to find the solution myself so I'll write it here in case anyone ever gets the same issue.

Turns out the problem was in my `@escaping` closure syntax. I didn't provide the capture list and the linker had issues with it, possibly due to a possibility of retain cycle. Also since I will be using a `weak self` within the closures, I will now have to use optional chaining for all calls to `self`.

So I went through all my closures and changed their syntax from

```
lazy var someOperationSuccess = {(someStringParameter: String?, someIntParameter: Int?) -> Void in
            print ("Success")
            self.doSomething()
        }
```

to

```
lazy var someOperationSuccess: (String?, Int?) -> Void = {[weak self] someStringParameter, someIntParameter in
        print ("Success")
        self?.doSomething()
    }
```